# WordPress Custom Taxonomy display category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Having problems solving a basic (but new to me) custom taxonomy issue--I have used the 
get_the_category() function quite a bit in my theme.  Namely as a "search and replace" if you will

foreach((get_the_category()) as $category)  pulls the category of "state" and is used:

/images/States/' . $category->cat_name . '.png
(category= colorado, then it pulls colorado.png)

Easy. Great. but....I would like to do this same thing with a custom taxonomy but can't figure out how to get it to work.

I have a Custom Post Type of "City Pages" (city_pages)
For those pages I have created a taxonomy of "State"  (state)
(these have to be different than the "categories" of state)

I have looked, I have researched and I cannot figure out how to do this. I know there are similar questions/problems out there but I have not been able to put 2 and 2 together in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

So it woud be something along the lines of:

```
<?php
    $states = get_terms( 'state' );
    foreach( $states as $state ) {
        echo '<img src="./images/States/' . $state->name . '.png">'; 
    }
?>
```